# foursquare home venues from api are fuzzed even with oauthed using creator account

Tags: foursquare

According to the blog entry about fuzzing foursquare, creators and their friends should be able to see the map pin of a foursquare venue categorized as a home: http://blog.foursquare.com/2011/09/29/making-your-house-into-a-home/

I'm pretty sure this was true through the API, not just the foursquare site or apps, until sometime in the recent past. Now, it doesn't matter if the OAuth token belongs to the creator in question, I'm seeing that home venues always have isFuzzed: true returned.

Is this a bug or a deliberate change to the API behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It was a deliberate change to the behavior because some apps were fetching venue information using the user's credentials and then caching the information for public display. Now home venue information is only displayed to authorized users of official apps.

This change wasn't widely announced as it wasn't believed to break any existing apps (documented in the changelog: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/changelog). If you have a use case that it breaks we'd like to hear about it: e-mail api@foursquare.com with details.